# Is it possible to perform morphological operations (opening, closing, etc.) on raster data in r?

Tags: r, raster

I am currently perform several progressive morphological operations (erosion, dilation, opening, closing) on a image using the `mmand` package.
Because this package only works with a matrix, I previously converted my raster with a spatial reference system (geoTIFF) to a matrix.

The Problem: within the conversion I lost the spatial information.

My question: Is there a possibility to perform morphological operations on a raster and to keep the reference system? Or is it somehow possible to keep the reference system after converting the raster to a matrix?

Any suggestions how to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm not familiar with these operations - do they change the extent or spatial resolution of the matrix? If not, you might be able to just slot the data back into raster format with the original extent/res/crs.

Comment: Assuming that `r` is your raster, `r[]<-matrix` equivalent to `r <- setValues(r, matrix)` will replace all the values of your initial raster with the new one stored in the matrix